# Deriving BIC, uniform prior

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am self-studying derivation of BIC. To be honest my background in probability and calculus is not fresh and superb and this is definitely why I am stuck on this particular part of derivation. [image: slide for the derivation]
Could someone explain how setting the uniform prior for the parameters theta allows me to drop the density function inside the integral? Thank you!

Comment: What does uniform mean in this context (over what interval)?

Comment: @TheLaconic Theta is set of model parameters and assuming uniform prior means that the probability for each set of parameters theta is equally probable. The interval is not specified but if theta falls outside the interval then there is zero probability

Comment: If theta is uniformly distributed, then p(theta) is a constant, which you can pull out to the front of the integral.  Taking the log then just turns that into some additive constant.  Without more context (what does "approximately equal" mean in this context?  Are we taking the derivative of this anyway, so that an additive constant is irrelevant?  Is this book any good?), I don't know whether that's all there is to it.